# Does qsort demand consistent comparisons or can I use it for shuffling?

Tags: c, sorting, random

**Update**: Please file this under bad ideas.  You don't get anything for free in life and here is certainly proof.  A simple idea gone bad.  It is definitely something to learn from however.

Lazy programming challenge.  If I pass a function that 50-50 returns true or false for the qsort's comparision function I think that I can effectively unsort an array of structures writing 3 lines of code.

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );  /* 1 */
    ...
    /* qsort(....) */     /* 2 */
}
```

...

```
int comp_nums(const int *num1, const int *num2)
{
    float frand = 
          (float) (rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX+1.0));  /* 3 */

    if (frand >= 0.5f)
         return GREATER_THAN;
    return LESS_THAN;
}
```

Any pitfalls I need to look for?  Is it possible in fewer lines through swapping or is this the cleanest I get for 3 non trivial lines?

Comment: The change made it worse. Now, the function never returns equality.

Comment: I thought you were free to pick one or the other for equality...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bad idea. I mean really bad.

Your solution gives an **unpredictable** result, not a **random** result and there is a **big** difference. You have no real idea of what a qsort with a random comparison will do and whether all combinations are equally likely. This is the most important criterion for a shuffle: all combinations must be equally likely. Biased results equal big trouble. There's no way to prove that in your example.

You should implement the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) (otherwise known as the Knuth shuffle).

Comment: qsort is really taking much longer than I expect... I think it expects the elements to be provably monotonic with respect to the comparison function....

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, this is worse than a simple Fisher-Yates shuffle because it is too slow. The qsort algorithm is O(n*log(n)), the Fisher-Yates is O(n).

Some more detail is available in Wikipedia on why this kind of "shuffle" does not generally work as well as [the Fisher-Yates method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle):

> Comparison with other shuffling
>   algorithms
>
> The Fisher-Yates shuffle is quite
>   efficient; indeed, its asymptotic time
>   and space complexity are optimal.
>   Combined with a high-quality unbiased
>   random number source, it is also
>   guaranteed to produce unbiased
>   results. Compared to some other
>   solutions, it also has the advantage
>   that, if only part of the resulting
>   permutation is needed, it can be
>   stopped halfway through, or even
>   stopped and restarted repeatedly,
>   generating the permutation
>   incrementally as needed. In high-level
>   programming languages with a fast
>   built-in sorting algorithm, an
>   alternative method, where each element
>   of the set to be shuffled is assigned
>   a random number and the set is then
>   sorted according to these numbers, may
>   be faster in practice[citation
>   needed], despite having worse
>   asymptotic time complexity (O(n log n)
>   vs. O(n)). Like the Fisher-Yates
>   shuffle, this method will also produce
>   unbiased results if correctly
>   implemented, and may be more tolerant
>   of certain kinds of bias in the random
>   numbers. However, care must be taken
>   to ensure that the assigned random
>   numbers are never duplicated, since
>   sorting algorithms in general won't
>   order elements randomly in case of a
>   tie. A variant of the above method
>   that has seen some use in languages
>   that support sorting with
>   user-specified comparison functions is
>   to shuffle a list by sorting it with a
>   comparison function that returns
>   random values. However, this does not
>   always work: with a number of commonly
>   used sorting algorithms, the results
>   end up biased due to internal
>   asymmetries in the sorting
>   implementation.[7]

This links to [here](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2007/06/19/a-simple-shuffle-that-proved-not-so-simple-after-all/):

> just one more thing While writing this
>   article I experimented with various
>   versions of the methods and discovered
>   one more flaw in the original version
>   (renamed by me to `shuffle_sort`). I was
>   wrong when I said “it returns a nicely
>   shuffled array every time it is
>   called.”
>
> The results are not nicely shuffled at
>   all. They are biased. Badly. That
>   means that some permutations (i.e.
>   orderings) of elements are more likely
>   than others. Here’s another snippet of
>   code to prove it, again borrowed from
>   the newsgroup discussion:

```
N = 100000
A = %w(a b c)
Score = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
N.times do
  sorted = A.shuffle  
  Score[sorted.join("")] += 1
end

Score.keys.sort.each do |key|
  puts "#{key}: #{Score[key]}"
end
```

> This code
>   shuffles 100,000 times array of three
>   elements: a, b, c and records how many
>   times each possible result was
>   achieved. In this case, there are only
>   six possible orderings and we should
>   got each one about 16666.66 times. If
>   we try an unbiased version of `shuffle`
>   (`shuffle` or `shuffle_sort_by`), the
>   result are as expected:

```
 
 abc: 16517
 acb: 16893
 bac: 16584
 bca: 16568
 cab: 16476
 cba: 16962
```

> Of course,
>   there are some deviations, but they
>   shouldn’t exceed a few percent of
>   expected value and they should be
>   different each time we run this code.
>   We can say that the distribution is
>   even.
>
> OK, what happens if we use the
>   shuffle_sort method?

```
 abc: 44278 
 acb: 7462
 bac: 7538
 bca: 3710
 cab: 3698
 cba: 33314
```

> This is not
>   an even distribution at all. Again?

It shows how the sort method is biased and goes into detail why this is so. FInally he links to [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html):

> Let's take a look at the correct
>   Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

```
for (int i = cards.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  int n = rand.Next(i + 1);
  Swap(ref cards[i], ref cards[n]);
}
```

> Do you see the difference? I missed
>   it the first time. Compare the swaps
>   for a 3 card deck:

```
 
Naïve shuffle   Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle
rand.Next(3);    rand.Next(3);
rand.Next(3);    rand.Next(2);
rand.Next(3);
```

> The naive shuffle
>   results in 3^3 (27) possible deck
>   combinations. That's odd, because the
>   mathematics tell us that there are
>   really only 3! or 6 possible
>   combinations of a 3 card deck. In the
>   KFY shuffle, we start with an initial
>   order, swap from the third position
>   with any of the three cards, then swap
>   again from the second position with
>   the remaining two cards.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't properly shuffle the array, it will barely move elements around their original locations, with exponential distribution.

Comment: The proof is too long to post here. By shuffle, we understand that any possible permutation is possible with equal probability. Since your compare function returns true with 50% probability, the number of comparisons needed to return true has exponential distribution with average 1/a = 2.0. So since, in two comparisons average you get a true result, that pivoting stops quickly, near the original place where the value was.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function isn't supposed to return a boolean type, it's supposed to return a negative number, a positive number, or zero which `qsort()` uses to determine which argument is greater than the other.

Comment: Ah, but a [[ToNumber]] conversion is performed on the result turning the boolean into either 0 or 1.  It's just less efficient :D

Comment: Wow, I suck, despite having read everything i am so used to encountering this in JS that i just assumed the code must be in JS

(JavaScript engines actually need to perform reasonably in this scenario.  It's stupid.)

Comment: Actually in C there is no boolean type, we just define TRUE as the number 1 and FALSE as 0. But with the comparison function you have to return a negative value sometimes so you can't use TRUE and FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

[The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/08/9595334.aspx) takes on this one

I think the basic idea of randomly partition the set recursively on the way down and concatenate the results on the way up will work (It will average O(n*log n) binary decisions and that is darn close to log2(fact(n)) but q-sort will not be sure to do that with a random predicate.

BTW I think the same argument and issues can be said for any O(n*log n) sort strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Rand isn't the most random thing out there... If you want to shuffle cards or something this isn't the best. Also a Knuth shuffle would be quicker, but your solution is ok if it doesn't loop forever