# Assign values to Button Randomly

Tags: jquery, random

I have one random variable which selects any random numbers between 1-10. I want to create a question in which user will have to guess the random number which is generated. I want to give user 4 options.

I have 4 distinct variables `a`,`b`,`c` and `rand`.

```
function generateOption()
{

var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)+1);
    var arr = [];
    var n,a,b,c;
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        do{
            n = Math.floor(Math.random()*9+1);
            }
        while(arr.indexOf(n) !== -1&&n!=rand);

       arr[i] = n;
    //  alert(arr[i]); 
    }

    a=arr[0];
    b=arr[1];
    c=arr[2];
alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+rand);


}
```

I have four buttons like this

```
<table style="  margin: 0 auto;">
   <tr>
   <td><input id="nextbutton3" type="button" class="finish"></td><td></td><td><input id="nextbutton4" type="button" class="finish"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input id="nextbutton5" type="button" class="finish"></td><td></td><td><input id="nextbutton6" type="button" class="finish"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

I can assign values to buttons like this

```
$(function() {
        $("#nextbutton3").val(a);
        $("#nextbutton4").val(b);
        $("#nextbutton5").val(c);
        $("#nextbutton6").val(rand);
    });
```

But this will set correct answer stick to button6 always.

How can i assign value `a`,`b`,`c` and `rand` to the buttons randomly?   please help

Comment: question not clear.. Plz be specific

Comment: I did it in my script outside this function. I have used global variable. Edited my question

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool which part i dint make it clear?

Comment: You want to set random number from dash to dash range.. and to four button a,b,c ,rand... and what is the error you are getting..?

Comment: I want to assign my rand variable 1 to 10. And want to assign those 4 variable to buttons in such a way that the correct answer that is rand  do not stick to only selected button(say the ist button).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g6YTd/15/  Plz chk this fiddle ..this is how it is working right now .. what you want from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assignment also needs to be random. I'm going to suggest a different workflow:

```
function generateOptions() {
  var randomValues = [];
  var currentValue;

  // First, generate 4 random values in the 1-10 range
  while(randomValues.length < 4) {
    currentValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    // Avoid duplicates
    if(randomValues.indexOf(currentValue) < 0) {
      randomValues.push(currentValue);
    }
  }

  // Here, randomValues has 4 values
  // We then pick one to be the "right" one:

  var correctValue = randomValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

  return {
    options: randomValues,
    correct: correctValue,
  };
}
```

Then, to prepare the page:

```
$(function() {
  var setup = generateOptions();

  // Assign each of the values to a button
  $("#nextbutton3").val(setup.options[0]);
  $("#nextbutton4").val(setup.options[1]);
  $("#nextbutton5").val(setup.options[2]);
  $("#nextbutton6").val(setup.options[3]);

  // That's the selector I've deduced from your markup. Feel free to change it
  $("input.finish").on("click", function() {
    // We need to parse the .val() as int, since it returns a string
    var selectedValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

    if(selectedValue === setup.correct) {
      alert("Correct!");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  });
});
```

A simple working example: http://jsbin.com/moyuqaha/1/edit?html,js,output (press ctrl+enter while focused on the js window to reload the numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the 4 values in an array and randomize their order in the array, then just assign them to the buttons.

[Randomizing elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813935/randomizing-elements-in-an-array?answertab=votes#tab-top)