# Is it possible to take a string of 26 characters, A to Z, and scramble it without every repeating a character

Tags: string, random

I want to populate 26 edit boxes with the letters A to Z. **Already done**.
Now I want to click my Scramble button and rearrange all 26 letters randomly
without any letter repeating.
I've tried Delphi's Random, RandomRange, RanSeed, etc and various code snippets found via google
but none of them work.  I'm on XE8 if that helps.

Comment: This is a solved problem. Search for "Fisher-Yates shuffle".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to generate a random alphabet string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340974/efficient-way-to-generate-a-random-alphabet-string)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.  Most of the suggestions I've seen involve stringlists or listboxes which I didn't want to use. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and this method, which I found on http://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/ appears to work well for integers so I modified if for my alphabet sort. I've run this multiple times and it seems fine to me but I'm just a Delphi Dabbler.....

// USING the simple Satolo cycle to unsort

```
Procedure SortIntegerList;
var a : Array of cardinal;
    i,j : integer;
      t : cardinal;
   Letter : String[1];
   Scrambled : String;
begin
  randomize;
  a := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
  i := length(a);
  while i > 0 do
    begin
     dec(i);
     j := randomrange(Low(a),i);
     t := a[i];
     a[i] := a[j];
     a[j] := t;
     Letter := Chr(a[i]+64);
     Scrambled := Scrambled + Letter +', ';
    end;
  ShowMessage('UnSorted - '+Scrambled);
end;
```